# PrimeNG p-calendar: display week of year in input field

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am using PrimeNG `<p-calendar>`:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="mydate" view="date" dateFormat="MM yy" [readonlyInput]="true">
```

I would like to display the week of the year and the year in the input field, which doesn't seem to be possible with `dateFormat` according the [docs](https://primeng.org/calendar#format). Is there a way to customize the format of the date display in the input field? I am using [ngx-moment](https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment) and I could render the desired text like this:

```
{{mydate | amDateFormat:'[Week ]WW Y'}}
```

Which results in:

```
Week 11 2024
```

Is there a way to bring a template string into the input field? Or any other trick? Note, that I have set the input field read only with `[readonlyInput]="true"`. So it's not a problem if the string is not parsable back into a date.